# How to compile keosd with Secure Enclave support?

Tags: wallet, security, build

I've followed the steps outlined here https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4604 and gathered the required info. I'm trying this on a Mac with T2 chip.

For `Step 3`, how should I modify the `eosin_build.sh` script in order to build `keosd` with `SecureEnclave` support ?